# Comparison of multiple diagnostic tests with paired data

Tags: paired-data, mcnemar-test

Good Day All,

I am attempting to compare three diagnostic tests against a gold-standard and for simplicity sake, let us have all the outcomes be binary (disease/no disease).

In this study study, all participants received the four tests (e.g. everyone got the gold-standard and three competing tests).

I see that McNemar's Test is a great way for comparing two tests (A & B) by analyzing the homogeneity of how often the agree/disagree with the gold-standard.  What about three tests against the gold standard ?

It is my understanding that Bhapkar's Test and/or Maxwell-Stuart Tests are generalizations of McNemar's Test but for more than two outcomes, not more than two tests.

Are there other generalizations of other tests that I can use ?

Thanks in advance !